# Using layout_weight changes the textview size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have two TextViews which I want to be centered (in the middle) and they should have a fix Size of about 30 dp, how can I achieve that?

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView

    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="N"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"  android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="N"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"  android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in your LinearLayout

Something similar to this:

```
    <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="N"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"  android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="N"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"  android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!!

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:padding="7dp"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="N"
android:background="@color/black"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="N"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
```